Primefaces pages loading slowly after jQuery version increased
My previous Primefaces version was 6.0. I upgraded it to Primefaces 10.0 (with help from the migrate section on their website.) There are no errors in Clean&Build and Debug. Although there was no problem with the upgrade, almost 50% of the time, web pages load slowly or do not load at all.
I discovered that this problem starts after Primefaces 6.2. In primefaces 6.2 jQuery version increased to version 3.2.1. The only change I made is that I updated js files in terms of on('load'), by removing the .load() function. There is a slowness problem, but there are no errors in the browser console.
Then, I installed jQuery 2.2.4 by using custom handler in Primefaces 10 and this fixed the problem. So, the problem starts after jquery goes above 3.0.x. But, I can't use 2.2.4 for two reasons. First, server-side deployment does not happen when I use custom handler for jQuery. Secondly, it provides an environment for security vulnerabilities.
What could be causing this problem above 3.0.x, and how can I solve it?

EDIT:

CONSOLE WARNING: jQuery(window).on('load'...) called after load event occurred
@Melloware
I had this code in resources/default/js/menu.js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(window).load(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(LOADER).fadeOut('slow', function () {
            });
        }, LOADER_DELAY);
});
});

I changed it to:
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(window).on("load",function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(LOADER).fadeOut('slow', function () {
            });
        }, LOADER_DELAY);
});
});

Now, with using jquery-migrate plugins I got the warning
on("load") event starts after load event
I seperated code into:
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    
});

$(window).on("load",function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(LOADER).fadeOut('slow', function () {
            });
        }, LOADER_DELAY);
});

It loads the page now, but does it good approach?
EDIT2:
If I seperate code like that (seperating document ready and on load), the application does not deploy on server. I change the file located in webapp/resources/default/js/menu.js. When I turn back to old state, it deploys on the server. Deploy failure does not give any errors. Somehow, the change in this js file breaks server deploy. How can I solve this?

Hmmm that is strange I have never heard of this before.  What did you changed your load() function it sounds like that is where your issues began?  Also are you using the performance suggestions like MOVE_SCRIPTS_TO_BOTTOM found here: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/14_0_0/#/core/performance?id=performance

@Melloware Hi, thank you, could you check the edit section in question please?

Okay, I solved both web pages do not load and the application cannot deploy on the server problem by changing this:
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(window).on("load",function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(LOADER).fadeOut('slow', function () {
            });
        }, LOADER_DELAY);
});
});

Into this:
(function($) {
    $(window).on("load", function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(LOADER).fadeOut('slow', function () {
            });
        }, LOADER_DELAY);
    });
})(jQuery);

Also, removing jQuery(document).ready() completely, instead of leaving it there blank.
